# How to scale the size of an jpg image

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-bitmap

With a click, my user can share a jpeg in social media or whatsapp.

The code works fine, but the jpeg is a little bit washed-out:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/share.jpg";
            OutputStream out = null;
            File file = new File(path);
            try {
                out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            path = file.getPath();
            Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://"+path);
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Post with"));
```

The jpeg file in in res\drawable-hdpi folder. I try to change the folder, but no effect. The jpeg file is 185*200 pixels

Comment: If you scale up or scale down the image to a larger extent, it is obvious that the image will look washed out, You have to maintain the aspect ratio of the image in order to make it look presentable. However you can use `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` method to scale an image. :)

Comment: I don't wan't to scale up or down the image. I only want to share this image in original size

Comment: Are you showing the image in any of the layout where the `layout_width` and `layout_height` is `match_parent` ? If yes, change the values to `wrap_content`.

Comment: no, the image is in the folder and I share the image on social media, not in my app, not in my layouts

Comment: can you tell me where is the image looking washed out? is it after sending the image ?

Comment: yes. in my folder res\drawable-hdpi the jpg is in original size and not washed out. But If i use my code, the jpg is washed out in facebook, in whatsapp and in the user folder ...getExternalStoragePublicDirectory..share.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147372/discussion-between-sripadraj-and-silverblue).